# trouble styling p class

Tags: css

I'm having trouble styling `<p class="wp-caption-text">`.

I've tried `.detail p.wp-caption-text`, `.detail .wp-caption-text`, `.wp-caption-text`, and so on. Nothing seems to work. What am I missing?

index.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<!-- #content -->
<div id="content">
    <!-- start of .post -->
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="post<?php if(!has_post_thumbnail()) echo " no-featured"; ?>">
        <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
        <div class="featured">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(700,9999)); ?></a>

        <div class="credit"></div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="detail">
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <?php if (the_post_thumbnail_caption()) { echo '<p class="wp-caption-text">' . the_post_thumbnail_caption() . '<p>'; }?>
            <div class="meta">
                <div class="top"></div>
                <p><?php _e('by'); ?> <strong><?php the_author(); ?></strong></p>
                <p><?php _e('posted'); ?>  <strong><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></strong></p>
                <p><?php _e('category'); ?>  <?php the_category(', '); ?></p>
                <div class="bottom"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="excerpt">
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </div>

            <?php 
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'attachment',
                    'numberposts' => -1,
                    'post_status' => null,
                    'post_parent' => $post->ID
                    ); 
                $attachments = get_posts($args);
                if(count($attachments) > 1): 
            ?>
            <div class="pic-excerpt">
                <div class="top"></div>
                <div class="outer">
                    <h3><?php _e('Pictures In This Set'); ?></h3>
                    <div class="pic">
                        <?php the_image_excerpt(wpop_get_option('pic_excerpt')); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bottom"></div>
            </div> <!-- pic-excerpt -->
            <?php endif; ?>

        </div>
    </div>

    <?php endwhile;?>
    <div class="paging">
        <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries', 0); ?></div>
        <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;', 0); ?></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <?php endif;?>
    <!-- end of .post -->
```

[Live site.](http://dapculture.com)

Comment: On your live site, there's nothing on the page with a class of `wp-caption-text`

Comment: how is the live site changed from index.php? how do i get the css to grab whatever is causing the caption to show? when i use firebug, the text is there just below the h2 title, but you're right- it's not wrapped in anything despite being wrapped within <p> in index.php..

Comment: ah, nevermind. i wrapped the php within <p> and changed the css to `.detail p` which made it all work. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7):

you're not closing your paragraph tag on this line-

```
   <?php if (the_post_thumbnail_caption()) { echo '<p class="wp-caption-text">' . the_post_thumbnail_caption() . '<p>'; }?
```

here is a fix

```
 <?php if (the_post_thumbnail_caption()) { echo '<p class="wp-caption-text">' . the_post_thumbnail_caption() . '</p>'; }?
```

Comment: that helps a lot, thank you. i'm still having issues with getting the css to grab. what i have right now is this:
`.detail p.wp-caption-text {
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 8px;
}
`

Answer (score 0):

i wrapped the php within

and changed the css to .detail p which made it all work. thanks for your help.